# Why is there still blank space?

Tags: html, css

This is HTML code of my site's skeleton:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<link href="css/base.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >    
</head>
<body>
<div id="center">
</br>
</br>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is how base.css looks like:

```
#center{
border:0px;
margin:0px auto;
width:960px;
background-color: #66ffff;
padding:0px;
}
```

The problem is that there is still blank space upon my website, here is a picture:
http://s4.postimage.org/6fagq090d/Untitled.png
(red arrow points which space I thought would disappear putting border, margin and padding on 0).

"auto" on margin I've put so it aligns always on center, but I'm not getting why can't I move this space. I've tried deleting space between  and  so it would be like  but it didn't help. Where I'm making mistake?

Comment: Probably because `body{padding:0}` hasn't been applied.

Comment: The next time please link to a demo page instead of a screenshot

Comment: Yea, that was the problem, thanks

Comment: This has to be the most-asked question on SO. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4501007/small-margin-gap-at-the-top-of-document/4501027#4501027

Comment: You need to set the style for the <body> element. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058179/html-blank-i-want-to-erase?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need to remove the margin around html and body :

```
html, body {
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, I couldn't find problem

Answer (score 1):

Your `<body>` most likely has a margin/padding. Zero those, too:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need reset the `body` like this,

```
body {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add body{margin:0;padding:0}   to your css there will be some space